# Make a vector a certain size without using push_back

Tags: c++, vector

I want to make my vector size 3. I tried `.reserve(3)` but that didn't work.

```
vector<Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer>> asteroidIndexBuffers;
asteroidIndexBuffers.reserve(3);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`reserve` only reserves room for the vector to grow to that size without reallocation, it doesn't actually change the size. `resize(3)` is the function you want =)

Comment: worked like a charm. thanks buddy :) (ill mark as answer asap)

Comment: If you want to know a bit more about how std::vector works in general (also the article I first learned the difference between resize/reserve in) http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/074.htm is a great article as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just give `3` as a parameter while declaring the vector - `vector<Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer>> asteroidIndexBuffers(3);`

Comment: vector<Microsoft::WRL::ComPtr<ID3D11Buffer>> asteroidVertexBuffers(3); - ERROR: expected a type specifier

Comment: I did, it's after the - :)

Comment: Missing space `> >` maybe for pre [tag:c++11]. Would also work, besides of `resize()`, but may be not applicable for all situations.